# Is there CarPlay Simulator in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.3, carplay

Is there a CarPlay Simulator available in Xcode or from another source? I would like to view if my current app has any interaction with it such as how notifications received from my app are displaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be anwered with both yes and no.

Yes, as in: there are emulators and tools available for Carplay, but only for companies that have enrolled in [Apple's MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/).

No, as in: it is very likely not available for you or your company, unless you or your clients have multiple manufacturer plants.

If you want further details, I've added a longer answer in the SO question [Is iOS CarPlay API Public? How to Integrate CarPlay?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38541642/1039247).

That being said, there is mentioning of some users who have successfully enabled the Carplay simulator with XCode, like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32723237/switch-between-carplay-and-regular-window-in-ios-simulator).

Answer (score 34):

Actually there is a CarPlay "External Display" that can be enabled, for it to show up you simply need to type in this command in a Terminal window:

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator CarPlay -bool YES
```

Then shutdown and restart the Simulator.

Answer (score 11):

As of iOS 12 and Xcode 10, CarPlay is available as an "external" display in the Xcode simulator menu.

(Note that this doesn't mean CarPlay will register itself as an additional `UIScreen` though.)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  External Displays is available under the Hardware menu when you launch the iPhone Simulator.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I agree with @bvmobileapps

Answer (score 3):

To access CarPlay in Simulator, select I/O, External Displays, and CarPlay.